# Can I apply Barbalat's lemma when the derivative of a function approaches a uniformly continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but Barbalat's lemma says that if $f(t)$ approaches a limit as $t$ approaches infinity, and if it's derivative $\dot{f}(t)$ is uniformly continuous, then $\dot{f}$ must approach 0.

I was wondering, if I can show that $\dot{f}$ approaches a uniformly continuous function $g(t)$, for $f(t)$ approaching some limit can I still say that $\dot{f}$ approaches 0 even if it only approaches a uniformly continuous function rather than being one?

I think I have shown that for any $\epsilon>0$, I can show there exists some value $\delta>0$ and some value $T$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $(x,y)>T$ where $|x-y|<\delta$. This seems like it could be used to still state Barbalat's lemma to guarantee convergence past $T$, but I'm not sure. Also, where can I find a proof of Barbalat's lemma? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Minecraft dirt block! I will refer to the following [proof of Barbălat's lemma](https://planetmath.org/proofofbarbalatslemma). Note that the case you mention is a consequence of this general setting by considering $y = f'$. The idea with uniform continuity, as seen in the proof, is that it gives an important estimate: $|y(t)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $t$ with $|t_n - t| \leq \delta_\varepsilon.$ Let's proceed in the same way with the proof and see if we can tinker it to serve our goal. Thus let's assume that $y$ is simply continuous, not necessarily uniformly continuous and approaches a uniformly continuous function $g$ in some way.

We will still proceed by contradiction and deduce the existence of a sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to infinity such that $|y(t_n)| \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n$. Eventually passing to a subsequence, we can assume $y(t_n) \geq \varepsilon$ (if necessary, we can replace $y$ by $-y$). Note that the continuation of the proof doesn't work in the same way, but we have that $|y(t_n) - y(t)| \leq |y(t_n) - g(t_n)| + |g(t_n) - g(t)| + |g(t) - y(t)|,$ so if we can control the first and last quantities we would be done. Thus, let's assume that $\lim_{t \to \infty} |y(t) - g(t)| = 0.$ This would mean that there is $M > 0$ such that $|y(t) - g(t)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{6}$ whenever $t > M.$ Once again (eventually passing to a subsequence) we can assume this is true for all of the $t_n$'s. Furthermore, by the uniform continuity of $g,$ we can find $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|g(a) - g(b)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{6}$ whenever $|a - b| < \delta_\varepsilon.$ Putting all the pieces together, $|y(t_n) - y(t)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever $|t - t_n| < \delta_\varepsilon$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ In the same way as in the link provided we deduce that $|y(t)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for the same values of $t$ as above. Then the conclusion follows in the same way:
$$0\leftarrow|\int_0^{t_n + \delta_\varepsilon} y(t) dt - \int_0^{t_n} y(t) dt| = |\int_{t_n}^{t_n + \delta_\varepsilon} y(t) dt| = \int_{t_n}^{t_n + \delta_\varepsilon} |y(t)| dt \geq \frac{\varepsilon \delta_\varepsilon}{2} > 0,$$
thus reaching a contradiction. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I think this is pretty much what I ended up doing with the same link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I just extended the proof here:

https://planetmath.org/proofofbarbalatslemma

The uniform continuity here is only used to obtain a domain where the difference between the function values is less than a finite value which is determined by the assumed not convergent derivative. So, since I don't need this difference to be vanishing, I think I can just use what I have in the question to extend Barbalat's this proof.

Comment: Oops, someone else already posted the answer.